# Ubuntu Fails to upgrade (ERROR: Errors were encountered while processing: install-info)

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-center, update-manager

I am trying to update my system, but I get an error message. I tried using the Ubuntu Software and `apt-get upgrade`, but none of the methods seems to work. Ubuntu Software sticks and using the terminal I get this error:

```
Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing: install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the content of `/etc/environment`? Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same error. @DavidFoerster I will edit the question and include ```/etc/environment```

Comment: @aberration: Please don't! There's no way to be certain that it's precisely the same issue. Instead, please [open a new question](/questions/ask) and may be reference this one if you deem it relevant. If your question ends up with an answer you (or somebody) else may flag this one as a duplicate of yours if that's what it looks like.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sorry I already did it. It's under peer review. The things is that I have exactly  the same message of error word for word, number for number. Include the version number ```6.1.0.dfsg.1-5```

Comment: An identical error message points to the same *type* of error, not to an identical error.

Comment: OK I will make another poste ASAP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on apt-get: /usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 23: /etc/environment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages: Permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826806/error-on-apt-get-usr-sbin-update-info-dir-23-etc-environment-usr-local-li)